# Core Text's Paragraph's space is too huge on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, quartz-graphics, core-text

I used CoreText to render text as below:

> Another very common typesetting operation is drawing a single line of text to use as a label for a user-interface element.
>   In Core Text this requires only two lines of code, one to create the line object with an attributed string and another to draw the line into a graphic context.
>   but it shows how to create an attributes dictionary and use it to create.

obvious there're 3 paragraphs. and I use default `CTParagraphStyleSetting` so that the `ParagraphSpacing` and `ParagraphSpacingBefore` is set to 0 by default.

But the rendered result shows the space is too HUGE
[image: rendered text with 3 paragraphs]

Any idea to reduce the paragraph space?

Comment: Are you drawing this yourself using the normal Core Text functions or are you using some other component (e.g EGOTextView)?

Comment: @Joshua I just use normal Core Text functions on -DrawRect method.

Comment: Could you add the code that renders the following paragraph? There's a lot of stuff that could render the text like that

Answer (score 2):

This might help:
[Technical Q&A QA1698 - How do I work-around an issue where some lines in my Core Text output have extra line spacing?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1698/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010203)

Answer (score 1):

u can try

```
kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMinimumLineHeight
kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMaximumLineHeight
kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineSpacing
```